# C# application Microsoft Visual Studio update 17.5.2 weird affect - opening in blank browser debugging not original

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, default-browser

Updated to 17.5.2 today and am now getting a weird separate chrome browser for a C# application that opens instead of the default chrome browsers that has my login's and google account signed into. Wondering if anyone else is experiencing this? & how to set using an existing logged in Chrome user profile?

Seems to of taken into affect not after initial launch of the Web browser launch but after going through a debug process

Any indications on why this may be occurring is much appreciated.

Duplicated google chrome image:

[image: Duplicated chrome browsers tabs]

Visual Studio default browser:
[image: Web Browser set to google]

Windows default browser:
[image: Default web browsers set to chrome]

Answer (score 0):

Revert to previous installed 17.5.1 version seems to of fixed this issue for me. Now opens in the correct chrome profile
[image: 17.5.1 version]

Comment: This is recurring with the latest update. Unaccpecting my answer in the hopes that someone can provide a definitive solution.